# Using Cordova plugins with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

After adding a Cordova plugin using `meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.dialogs@0.2.10`, I see this plugin installed using `meteor list`.

However on the desktop browser console, I can't seem to find any methods exposed by `cordova:org.apache.cordova.dialogs`, such as `navigator.notification.alert`. How do we do something like

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
    'Hello there',
    onConfirm,
    'Welcome',
    ['Hey']
)
```

Also tried `cordova:org.apache.cordova.device@0.2.12` and the `device` object the plugin is supposed to expose globally cannot be found.

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    console.log(device.cordova)  // Uncaught ReferenceError: device is not defined
})
```

Comment: I am facing the same with "FileTransfer" plugin! Other than the 3 mdg packages i couldn't find guides on how to build a wrapping meteor-cordova package! --> Did you find anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of Cordova plugins is to give your JavaScript code access to some device-specific native features on mobile.

The features from Cordova plugins are not available on browsers.